# Optimize memory usage while cropping bitmap in rounded shape on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am using a method which returns a rounded Bitmap with Fill: Transparent Color in outer spaces of canvas. I am using that method in a custom adaptor to display images in rounded shape in a list but for some reason fill adapter is throwing "OutOfMemoryError" Exception.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage, int width){
    try {
        int targetWidth = width;
        int targetHeight = width;

        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);

        Path path = new Path();
        float x = ((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2;
        float y = ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2;
        float radius = (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float)targetHeight)) / 2);
        path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
        canvas.clipPath(path);

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        Rect sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight());
        Rect destRect = new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null);
        return targetBitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return scaleBitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `RoundedBitmapDrawable` to create rounded images http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting variables to null. This helps GC free some memory.